# 500 error; not specific enough

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, internal-server-error

I'm using Microsoft Visual Web Express 2012 for Web and had been testing through Firefox the entire time.

When I finally got it working, I then proceeded to try Chrome and IE, but on both browsers it reports back 500 internal server error in a little window.  The html loads fine.  I believe this is due to the fact that my website loads the database info in a tab widget.  Rechecked Firefox; seems fine.  Rechecked Chrome and IE; same error.

It's probably obvious by now, but I've commented out the ajax code and IE and Chrome doesn't report the 500 issue.

I wouldn't know how to find more details on this generic error.  I've tried

```
  <system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
    <asp scriptErrorSentToBrowser="true"/>
</system.webServer>
<system.web>
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
  <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
</system.web>
```

in my web.config, but that window doesn't show much else than the 500.  I've also tried unchecking "Show Friendly HTTP error messages" and "Disable script debugging (IE) and (Other)".  I'm not sure what's supposed to happen, but the 500 message doesn't change.

I do notice that Firefox does show a bizarre delay on loading from the database, but all the data in there is fine after loading.

This is the code in question.

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.Services.Protocols;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Text;
using System.Web.Script.Services;

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for serverAttempt2
/// </summary>
[WebService(Namespace = "http://idontcare.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
[ScriptService]

public class serverAttempt2 : WebService
{
  [WebMethod]
  public string GetCustomer(string CustomerID)
  {
    string response = "<p>No customer selected</p>";
    string connect = @"Data Source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=personnet;Integrated Security=Yes;";
    string query = "SELECT TOP 200 * FROM personnet.dbo.accordionTest";
    if (CustomerID != null && CustomerID.Length == 8)
    {
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
      using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connect))
      {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
        {
          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("CustomerID", CustomerID);
          conn.Open();
          SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
          if (rdr.HasRows)
          {
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                sb.Append("Hi.");
                response = sb.ToString();
                /*
                sb.Append("<table style='width:100%;'><tr><td style='width:180px;'>");
                sb.Append(rdr["pro"].ToString() + "</td><td style='width:20%;'>");
                sb.Append(rdr["sn"].ToString() + "</td><td style='width:10%;'>");
                sb.Append(rdr["po"].ToString() + "</td><td style='width:20%;' align='center'>");
                sb.Append(rdr["qty"].ToString() + "</td><td style='width:10%;' align='center'>");
                sb.Append(rdr["status"].ToString() + "</td><td style='width:20%;' align='center'>");
                sb.Append("<input type='image' src='images/temporaryStar.png' /></td></tr></table><div><p></p></div>");
                response = sb.ToString();*/
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    return response;
  }
}
```

I've heard of IE's rude compatibility surprises, but I don't think it's the case here.

EDIT:  Well, I've found something, but I'm not sure what to make of it.

```
'iexplore.exe' (Script): Loaded 'Script Code (Windows Internet Explorer)'. 
Exception was thrown at line 4, column 13743 in http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js
0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: SyntaxError
Exception was thrown at line 4, column 13957 in http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js
0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: SyntaxError
Exception was thrown at line 4, column 10598 in http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js
0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: SyntaxError
Exception was thrown at line 4, column 10598 in http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js
0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: SyntaxError
Exception was thrown at line 4, column 10598 in http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js
0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: SyntaxError
Exception was thrown at line 4, column 10598 in http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js
0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: SyntaxError
Exception was thrown at line 4, column 10598 in http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js
0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: SyntaxError
Exception was thrown at line 4, column 10598 in http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js
0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: SyntaxError
Exception was thrown at line 4, column 10598 in http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js
0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: SyntaxError
Exception was thrown at line 4, column 10598 in http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js
0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: SyntaxError
Exception was thrown at line 4, column 10598 in http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js
0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: SyntaxError
Exception was thrown at line 4, column 10598 in http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js
0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: SyntaxError
Exception was thrown at line 4, column 4377 in http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js
0x800a03f6 - JavaScript runtime error: Invalid character
```

Comment: Try running Fiddler whilst using IE to see exactly where it's failing.

Comment: A 500 internal server error often means that there's an exception being thrown in the server-side code.  I can't help but notice you're not catching or logging exceptions in your code.  Maybe there's an informative error that you're ignoring?

Comment: Have you tried to attach to the ASP.NET process? You can attach the debugger to w3wp.exe (Debug > Attach to Process...), and turn on catching of thrown exceptions.

Comment: Put a try catch in code, and Debug.Write the exception and update your post.

Comment: If you are debugging with visual studio, press `ctrl + alt + e` to bring up the `Exceptions dialogue`. Then check `thrown` under `Common Language Runtime Exceptions`. This will stop at most hidden errors.

Answer (score 0):

You should add the following to your web.config inside the `<system.web>`-node:

```
<customErrors mode="On|Off|RemoteOnly">
```

To show detailed error information set the value of `mode` to `Off`.

Comment: I believe I've tried that earlier.  I don't see any differences trying it again.

Comment: Basically what you're changing in your browser doesn't matter, it's the server that's just sending you an 500 with the non-descriptive HTML. If you want the full stack trace you can do so by changing the customerrors as in my answer. If you have that, but still don't know what the reason is, you should put a breakpoint in the code and step through it to see where it's going wrong.